# Linker error on Visual Studio 2008 C++: 32-bit library in 64-bit Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

Look, I've done my homework, googled and stack-overflowed and still can't manage it. So, pwleese, don't tell me to link my libraries with `Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional dependencies`, ok?

I have some 3rd party static libs built for Win32, and am trying to link a program using VS C++ 2008 in a 64-bit machine. The point is, I'm using WinXP 32-bit, VSC++ solution platform is set to Win32 **and** the same configuration works fine on a 32-bit machine. I can't rule out another source of stupidness from me, but until now this is the only thing that makes sense. Initially some pre-built Boost libraries wouldn't link too; after I compiled them, they worked.

The errors are all like this: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: ..."`

As I said, the same configuration works fine on another machine, although I did try to link the DLLs instead of static linking.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post the full text of the linker error?

Comment: In windows you cannot link a 32 bit library into a 64 bit project or application

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what files are missing or wrong.

Note that it usees the current PATH variable, which can affect your results.